# Row and column indexes of True values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have an NxN pandas DataFrame which contains booleans. For example:

```
In[56]: df
Out[56]: 
       15     25     35     45     55
10   True  False  False  False  False
20  False   True  False  False  False
30  False  False   True  False  False
40  False  False  False   True  False
50  False  False  False  False   True
```

What I need to do is collapse this frame into an Nx2 pandas DataFrame which has the index and column values that have `True` at the intersection as the record values. For example:

```
In[62]: res
Out[62]: 
    0   1
0  10  15
1  20  25
2  30  35
3  40  45
4  50  55
```

Can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) "unpivots" a DataFrame from wide to long format:

```
result = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'])
mask = result['value'] == True
result = result.loc[mask, ['index', 'variable']]
result.columns = [0, 1]
print(result)
```

yields

```
     0   1
0   10  15
6   20  25
12  30  35
18  40  45
24  50  55
```

---

PS. Your desired DataFrame has two columns which have values which act as coordinates. The `df.pivot` method converts DataFrames with coordinate-like columns into "wide-format" DataFrames like your original DataFrame. When you want to go the other way, use `pd.melt`.